# Докуда идёт этот трамвай?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, разговорная-речь

Насколько допустимо такое употребление *докуда* и, если так говорить не очень хорошо, как можно спросить иначе, но не очень академично, а естественно для обычной речи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что все хорошо в разговорном симбиозе "докуда идёт".

[**докуда**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0), наречие, разг.

1. До какого места, предела. ***Докуда ехать?*** В значении союза. *Поле раскинулось, докуда видит глаз.*
2. До каких пор. *Докуда терпеть будем?* В значении союза. *Докуда крестьянин на земле, он жив и крепок.*

Вот что есть на ["Грамоте"](https://gramota.me/dokuda-ili-do-kuda-kak-pravilno#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5,%2C%20%C2%AB%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%C2%BB.):
**докуда** — означает «до какого места», «до какого времени».
*— Вы не подскажете, **докуда едет** этот автобус?

Узнай, **докуда идёт** этот поезд и когда мы будем на конечной станции.*
— Скажи мне, докуда ты уже прочёл эту книгу?
Ты можешь прогонять меня сколько угодно, но докуда ты не ответишь на все мои вопросы — я не уйду.

Вот выдержка из книги Наталии Шведовой ["Русский язык. Избранные работы"](https://books.google.ee/books?id=GKcSAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA525&lpg=PA525&dq=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=vj8clhWgtI&sig=ACfU3U0F2PHzxqjMzvKTFZA9tVRn9uZiJA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC38OR6_DsAhXEtYsKHcdcBTQQ6AEwB3oECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0&f=false) (интересно, что автор называет слово местоимением): в общем ряду означений направления движения «откуда — куда — докуда» докуда означает конечную точку, «пункт назначения».
*Докуда-нидокуда, а дойдем. Докуда доберешься, а докуда и нет. Поклажа тяжелая, а ехать-то вон докуда!*

> — Бравенькая какая девочка! — похвалила она, возвращая голову на место. ― Докуда едут-то?
> ― Докуда билет велит.
> (В. Распутин. Нежданно-негаданно)

Comment: Ох уж это "подскажете"! Какая-то это не та Грамота.)) *Докуда ты не ответишь* — странно. Может, *покуда* всё-таки.

Comment: А что такое с _подскажете_? Что не так? У Ожегова: Докуда не ответишь, не уйду. (https://dicti.net/?ozhw=%E4%EE%EA%F3%E4%E0

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой У Ефремовой: доку́да, **2.** союз. 1) Употр. при присоединении придаточного предложения места; соответствует по значению сл.: до того места, куда. 2) Употр. при присоединении придаточного предложения времени; соответствует по значению сл.: **пока, до тех пор пока.**

Comment: Лучше просто "не скажете" или "скажите, пожалуйста". Подсказка — это всё-таки другое. А про значение "пока" я догадался, просто не нашёл его среди тех, что Вы привели.

Comment: 1. Мне кажется, что очень многое зависит от контекста. ― Простите, господин военный, ― сказал он, ― вы не подскажете, где тут магазин «Мужские сорочки»? [Виктор Пелевин. Generation «П» (1999)] Вы не подскажете, как мне пройти к зданию архива? [Александра Маринина. Иллюзия греха (1996)] (https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&endyear=2019&p=2) 2. Как же нет? Есть: До каких пор.

Comment: 2. Согласен, но "до каких пор" воспринимается как вопросительный вариант, а "до тех пор пока" утвердительный. Но сейчас смотрю: действительно у Вас в примере для "до каких пор" и есть утвердительный смысл. 2. Всё-таки раньше, в советское время, гораздо чаще говорили "скажите, пожалуйста" вместо ныне модного "подскажите, пожалуйста". То же и с "Вы не скажете...?"

Comment: Ой, надо было закончить первым, а я случайно повторил второй.